# Enabling chartsJS bar chart to start on y axis

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am using chartsJS to make a bar chart. however I want the br chart to have the bar protruding from the "Y" axis.
I thought my code below would do just that but for some reason i cannot get it to work. the bars are protruding from the x axis. I wonder where I am going wrong.

```
<div class="hello">
        <canvas id="sChartSum2" width="750" height="350"></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('sChartSum2').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                axis: 'y',
                data: {
                    labels: ["L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6"],
                    datasets: [{
                                axis: 'y',
                                label: 'My First Dataset',
                                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                                fill: false,
                                backgroundColor: [
                                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                                  'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
                                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                  'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                  'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                  'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                                  'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                                  'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                                  'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                                  'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
                                  'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                              }]
                },
                options: {
                    indexAxis: 'y',
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your options should work in v3, the `axis: 'y'` is no option for chart.js, since it doesnt work for you I assume you are using version 2 of the lib in which case you have to change your `type` from `bar` to `horizontalBar`